# Clone() body for deep cloning?

Tags: java

I'm stuck at this since a very long time.

tell me if the following code makes a clone or not?

```
class A
{  
 int i;
    int j;  
    String str;  
    A()  
    {  
      i=10;  
      j=30;  
      str="Hello";  
    }  
    A(A a)  
   {  
      this.i=a.i;  
      this.j=a.j;  
      this.str=a.str;  
   }  
}  
class B
{  
   public static void main(String args[])  
   {
      A a  = new A();  
      A a1 = new A(a);
      /* I want to make clone like this. */  
      } 
}
```

when I run this code and when I print hashcode of a and a1, they are different.
But some of my friends say that this is not the correct way to make a clone.
You have to implement the Cloneable interface, is that really necessary?
In my opinion, it can be a good approach if I want to make a deep copy even in case of derived reference variable.
Thank  you.

Comment: Your code does not make a deep copy, or even a shallow copy (`str` is different). Do you really want a deep copy? Also, your friends are right; what you have is called a _copy constructor_. It's a perfectly fine coding style. Also, unless you implement `hashcode()`, you should expect distinct objects to have distinct hash codes.

Comment: My code perfectly makes a deep copy. values of all the fields are same. Yes, that's a copy constructor which performs deep copy.'and obviously I haven't override hashcode() so I wont be getting equal hash codes. But why ain't it doing deep copy in your opinion?

Comment: First, you changed your code since I posted my comment, so part of my comment is now irrelevant. It does make a _shallow_ copy. However, if you want a deep copy, you'd need to do `this.str = new String(a.str)`. Since String is immutable, this is not a big deal at all, but it's not a deep copy, either.

Comment: I mentioned that I edited my code but the page is not showing that. Yes string objects are immutable(once created cant be changed, will always be a new object if changed). but in this case, its a deep copy I have checked it right now. change in my copied object's str is not affecting my original object's str.

Comment: That's not what is meant by a deep copy. Since instances of `String` are immutable, you cannot change them. You can only change the value of the `str` field in your objects. Replace `String str;` with some other object type that is mutable, such as `StringBuffer`. Then append a character to `a.str` and you'll see that the value of `a1.str` will have changed. That's because you are making a shallow copy of `a`.

Comment: public class A {
 int i;
 int j;
 StringBuffer str;
 A(){
  i=10;
  j=20;
  str=new StringBuffer("Hello");
 }
 A(A a){
  this.i=a.i;
  this.j=a.j;
  this.str=a.str;
  }
 void show()
 {
  System.out.println(str);
 }
 
}
class B{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = new A();
  A a1= new A(a);
  a.show();
  a1.show();
  a1.str=new StringBuffer("GM");
  a.show();
  a1.show();
  
 }
}

will you please run this code?
and change the StringBuffer to String also and then also notice the change.

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying. Change this line: `a1.str = new StringBuffer("GM");` to this: `a1.str.append("GM");`. Then see what happens when you call `a.show();`. It demonstrates that `a1` is not a deep copy of `a`. If it were, then nothing you did to `a1` (or any of its members) would affect `a`.

Comment: okk...now I got your point. I have to override clone() to get a clone. thanks for clearing my doubt. :)

Comment: How clone() method works internally. I mean what is the method body of clone() in actual?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), the default implementation is to do a shallow copy, not a deep copy. In the standard JRE, the actual cloning is implemented as a native method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the Clonable interface in order to clone an object. What you have implemented is called a copy constructor. Copy constructors are preferable to implementing Clonable.

The reason your copied object has a different hashcode/equals from the object it is copied from is because you haven't overridden the hashcode or equals functions in your A class so it's checking for identity rather than just equality (the *exact* same object, not an object with the same values). By overriding hashcode/equals you can make your class compare the values of it's properties instead.